# resize image based on the width

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I force the resize of a image maintaining the aspect ratio, but setting the width to 200px.
I have a lot of images, everyone of them are different sizes, some are larger and some wider. But I want that the width of each of them in the layout be 200px, no matter than some of them are higher than others. Next I explain more about it:

[image]

Comment: so just set the width and not the height...

Comment: @epascarello yes, I tried but it cut the image

Comment: Just set `width:200px` and `height:auto` or don't set height to anything and you're fine. H:W ratio is automatically maintained unless you set both to fixed values, such as `width:200px;height:200px;`. By default, in a 4:3 image, if you set `width:200px` and leave height alone, the height will be 150px. Please create a fiddle if it's cutting the image somewhere.

Comment: @epascarello yes,it work now, maybe there was a cache issue and I was no able to look it right

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width in CSS and leave the height as auto

```html
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQwMjAwNzI0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTY1MTMyOQ@@._V1_UY317_CR22,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" style="width: 200px; height:auto;">

<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQwMjAwNzI0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTY1MTMyOQ@@._V1_UY317_CR22,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" style="width: 300px; height:auto;">
```